# Why is R only sometimes mishandling slashes in file path to a remote server?

Tags: r, remote-server, remote-desktop, r-haven

I have several DTA files on a Windows remote server that I am trying to read into R with `haven::read_dta()` on a Windows remote desktop (the remote desktop accessed through Microsoft Remote Desktop on a Mac, but this shouldn't make any difference). The trouble is that R **only sometimes** fails to read in the files, and the error is inexplicable to me.

`Error: Failed to parse \\name/path/file.dta: Unable to read from file.`

When you look at this, you may say it looks obvious why it failed to parse the file path, because those backslashes would be treated as escape characters in R. But the line I am running that (again, only **sometimes**) results in that error looks like this:

`df <- haven::read_dta("//name/path/file.dta")`

I am doing everything exactly the same when this line succeeds and when it fails (and it does sometimes succeed, but not consistently enough for me to loop through the vector of file paths I have). And just in case, it doesn't matter whether I am running the following or the above:

```
file = "//name/path/file.dta"
df <- haven::read_dta(file)
```

I have made sure to connect to the remote server on this remote desktop (by going to File Explorer > This PC > Computer > Add a network location) and adding the network in the format "\\name\path" before doing anything else, and I can confirm from the command prompt that the Windows remote desktop is indeed connected to the remote server. I am using the most updated version of R.

How do I prevent this error? Any help would be much appreciated!

**EDIT** It's hard to confirm but it appears that actually the error only occurs when the files are in a vector. Otherwise the error is intermittent. So `df <- haven::read_dta("//name/path/file.dta")` should always succeed, but `df <- haven::read_dta(file)` only sometimes. This doesn't resolve when `file <- file.path(file)` is run before `read_dta()`.

Comment: Could you review your first sentence? It's hard to understand.

Comment: @jay.sf all fixed

Comment: I still do not understand what operating system are you using on your machine and what operating system is running on the server?

Comment: @jay.sf they're both Windows

Answer (score 0):

When working with paths I always use `file.path()`, which constructs paths in a platform-independent way, so you don't have to worry about Windows vs Mac and can use Unix-style slashes in your paths all the time. For example,

```r
file_path <- file.path("/name/path/file.dta")
df <- haven::read_dta(file_path)
```

That should fix things if the issue is indeed weirdness with backslashes.

Comment: This works but not when ```file <-  "//name/path/file.dta"``` and ```file_path <- file.path(file)```

Comment: So you file path actually begins with "//"? I don't think there is any directory structure like that...are you sure using one "/" at the beginning doesn't work?

Comment: Yep, it starts with a double forward-slash because the directory is on a Windows remote server that I am connected to as I detail in the initial question. Using a single slash tells me the file does not exist.